# Centering p element and div in menu bar

Tags: html, css

Trying to vertically center a p element and an image. I know I could adjust the margins and padding, but I want to make sure the elements are aligned no matter what device the user enters the website on. Hence I'm looking for another option.

```css
html, body {
 font-size: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;
}
/*Menu*/
.menu {
 height: auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
}
.menu .logo {
 padding-left: 2em;
}
.menu ul li a {
 color: #3b3a36;
}
.menu .dropdown {
 float: right;
 right: 2em;
 z-index: 20;
}
.menu .dropdown-menu {
 background: #fff;
 border: none;
}
.dropdown img {
 height: 2.8em;
 width: 2.8em;
 -webkit-transition: width .8s, height .8s, -webkit-transform .8s; /* Safari */
 transition: width .8s, height .8s, transform .8s;
}
.dropdown ul {
 top: 3em;
 left: -6.5em;
 width: auto;
 position: absolute;
 color: #3DD0AC;
}
.rotate {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari */
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.logo p {
 font-size: 100%;
 color: black;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: bolder;
 letter-spacing: 0.5em;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="logo">
    <p>&lt;&frasl;BY&#95;John Doe&gt;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown"> <img src="img/menu.jpg">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Find me on Linkedin</a>
      <li>
      <li><a href="#">Send me an email</a></li>
      <li><a href="/docs/Resume.pdf" download="Resume">Download my resume</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flex box can acheive this for you. just add this to your css for `.menu`:

```
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center
```

More settings for flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/*Menu*/

.menu {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #6ed3cf;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center
  }

.menu .logo {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #3b3a36;
}

.menu .dropdown {
  float: right;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 20;
}

.menu .dropdown-menu {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown img {
  height: 2.8em;
  width: 2.8em;
  -webkit-transition: width .8s, height .8s, -webkit-transform .8s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width .8s, height .8s, transform .8s;
}

.dropdown ul {
  top: 3em;
  left: -6.5em;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  color: #3DD0AC;
}

.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.logo p {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="logo">
    <p>&lt;&frasl;BY&#95;John Doe&gt;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <img src="img/menu.jpg">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Find me on Linkedin</a>
        <li>
          <li><a href="#">Send me an email</a></li>
          <li><a href="/docs/Resume.pdf" download="Resume">Download my resume</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Also for other sections on my site. Thanks @Brad!